# How can I install the driver for my EPSON NX430 printer?

Tags: installation, drivers, printing

I have a new printer, an Epson nx430. I've followed the instructions so far and the printer is on and cartridges in. I need to install the drivers from epsons support website before I plug in the printer to the computer (via usb).

http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX

Those are all the drivers. This is as far as I know how to go. I installed CUPS. Now I need to know:
1. which drivers to install (i'll do them all i don't care)
2. how do i do that after i download the file (it saves in my downloads folder)

I guess I need to know what to do once these driver files are on my computer. I would like to:

1. print from my desktop
2. print wirelessly from my laptop (windows 7)

I am new to linux.

Answer (score 0):

**SCANNER** you need see http://download.ebz.epson.net/faq/linux/faq_ls_00002.html

1. iscan-data_1.26.0-1_all.deb
2. iscan_2.29.3-1~usb0.1.ltdl7_[amd64 or i386].deb
3. iscan-network-nt_1.1.1-1_[amd64 or i383].deb

[copied from http://download.ebz.epson.net/faq/linux/faq_ls_00007.html]

1. Configure Image Scan! for Linux to connect to your device by editing
   /etc/sane.d/epkowa.conf. You need administrative privileges to do
   so. Read the instructions in the file about network configuration
   and add an entry for your device like this =>>>> 
   **net IPADDRESSOFTHESCANNER 1865**
2. Finally, disable the conflicting epson2 SANE backend. You can do so
   by changing the line consisting of "epson2" to "#epson2" in
   /etc/sane.d/dll.conf. This will require administrative privileges.

**PRINTER**

1. epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_1.3.1-1lsb3.2_[amd64 or i386].deb after
   you install the driver go to System Settings/Printers and add your
   printer it should work

tested Ubuntu 13.10 amd64 *used krusader to navigate through the folders*